# BlackBerry-how to change Manager background image?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, blackberry-jde

I am trying to create a tool bar with background color different from the screen background, 
i am using the following code

`getMainManager().add(mToolbarManager = new HorizontalFieldManager());
    mToolbarManager.add(mBtn = new BitmapButtonField(mBmpNor, mBmpFoc,
                    mBmpAct));
    Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.BLACK);
    mToolbarManager.setBackground(bg);
mToolbarManager.add(mBtn = new BitmapButtonField(mBmpNor, mBmpFoc,
                mBmpAct));`

but it doesn't effect the background of toolbarmanager, while setting the background of mainmanager works fine

Answer (score 3):

I got it , i used call HorizontalFieldManager constructor with USE_ALL_WIDTH parameter

Answer (score 1):

hey i know 1 more way that i used:

```
class Mymanager extends Manager
{
final Bitmap back = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("back.png");
Mymanager ()
{
 super(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
 {
  g.drawBitmap(0,0,back.getWidth(),back.getHeight,back,0,0);
 }
}
```

no add components to this manager